# Стек. Отображение в консоли Google Crome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль, рекурсия, стек

**1.**

[image: Рекурсия]

```js
function pow(x, n) {
 if (n != 1) {
  return x * pow(x, n - 1);
 } else {
  return x;
 }
}

console.log( pow(2, 3) );
```

Обычная рекурсия. Во время вызова функции создается `контекст выполнения`. При любом вложенном вызове `JavaScript` запоминает текущий `контекст выполнения` в специальной внутренней структуре данных – `стеке контекстов`. Для нового вызова создаётся свой `контекст выполнения`, и управление переходит в него, а когда он завершён – старый `контекст` достаётся из `стека` и выполнение внешней функции возобновляется. На картинке видны `стеки` и по ним можно перемещаться, смотреть какие у них были значение в `переменных`, `this`. Тут вроде все понятно.
Определения брал отсюда: [Современный учебник Javascript - Рекурсия, стек.](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion)

**2.**

[image: Рекурсия async]

```js
function pow(x, n) {
  if (n != 1) {
    return x * setTimeout(pow, 1000, x, n - 1);
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}

pow(2, 3);
```

1. Вызываем функцию pow с аргументами `x = 2`, `n = 3`.
2. Функция `pow` через return вызывает метода `setTimeout` с аргументом `pow`(рекурсия), который возвращает свой `id = 1` и по идеи вызов функции должен почиститься. Возможно есть правило, которое предотвращает зачишения функции, и в следствии в консоли будут отображаться `стеки`, но я ни где не нашел информации по этому поводу.

**2.1**

[image: async]

```js
setTimeout(function pow(x, n) {
  if (n != 1) {
    return x * setTimeout(pow, 1000, x, n - 1);
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}, 2000, 2, 3);
```

Это дополнению ко второму пункту. Здесь я передал анонимную функцию `pow` как аргумент методу `setTimeout` и хотел бы понять как оно работает, ибо теперь вызов `pow` стал асинхронным и это видно на изображении в `стеках`.

Итог:

**1.** В первом пункте вполне понятно зачем нужны `стеки` и в принципе как это работает. `Стеки` принадлежат вызову `pow`?

**2.** Тут не понятно почему стеки остаются, так как по идеи вызов pow должен вернуть `id` и удалиться. Я не утверждаю что это должно быть именно так, но информации я об это не нашел, а с английским все плохо как и с русским(предотвращаю сразу шутки про мою орфографию). Возможно в спецификации об этом что - то сказано [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) или же в API Google Chrome Console. `Стеки` принадлежат вызову `pow`?

**2.1.** Дополнение ко второму пункту. `Стеки` принадлежат вызову `setTimeout`?

Хочу разъяснить вопрос по поводу `кому принадлежат стеки?`. `setTimeout` это метод (функция), и я осмелился себе предположить что вызов проходит внутри нее.

**Вот пример:**

[image: пример]

```js
function func() {
    function pow(x, n) {
        if (n != 1) {
            return x * pow(x, n - 1);
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    }
 return pow(2, 3);
}

func();
```

В этом примере рекурсия происходит внутри вызова `func` и значит стек принадлежит этому же вызову(func). Если внимательно сравнить скриншот вызова через `setTimeout`, то видно что функция `pow` которая вызывается асинхронно, как будто вызывается в основном потоке, а не внутри метода `setTimeout`. Это все мои личные догадки на основе знаний, но так как я не знаю что под капотом, надеюсь вы мне поможете в этом разобраться. И в дополнение хочу еще добавить, что вроде как `setTimeout` просто создает массив в которой просто храниться очередь, и потом из нее(из очереди) идет уже вызов той функции, которую я туда передал.

**Пример:**

```js
function func() {
  return 1;
}

setTimeout(func, 2000);

setTimeout(func, 3000)

////////////

var queue = [
  {
    func: function func() {
      return 1;
    },
    start: new Date,
    delay: 2000,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    func: function func() {
      return 1;
    },
    start: new Date,
    delay: 3000,
    id: 2
  }
];
```

P.S: До этого я задал похожий вопрос и его сделали дубликатом. Я ознакомился с этим ответом, но он мне не помог. Возможно там объясняется основные понятия асинхронности, которые поменяю всю картину, но я ничего не понял из того что там написано, и в следствии не получил ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: кааак мнооого теееекста

Comment: Можешь как-то выделить что именно ты спрашиваешь?

Comment: Посмотри **что именно** возвращает [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: @Grundy не понимаю почему в консоли стеки. Разве плохо, то что я хочу разобраться?

Comment: тоже не понял, что именно он хотел узнать

Comment: @виталик где в консоли стеки?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, то, что хочешь разобраться, не плохо. Просто во втором примере у тебя код возвращает совсем не то, что ты думаешь, поэтому у тебя получаются странные выводы. Посмотри ссылку на дубликат, там написано про асинхронные функции и как получать из них значения, а так же ссылку на описание `setTimeout` в комментарии выше, чтобы стало понятно, что в твоем коде происходит что-то странное

Comment: @Grundy я не нашел что возвращает `setTimeout`. В дубликате я тоже ничего не нашел. Может вы перестанете мой вопрос делать дубликатом или просто человеческим языком ответите почему так происходит. И хочу заметить, что это были домысли, а не выводы. Прежде чем выносить вердикт, нужно было попробовать прочитать вопрос полностью.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный _я не нашел что возвращает setTimeout_ - [_var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);_, _timeoutID - это **числовой ID**, который может быть использован позже с window.clearTimeout()._](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) - надо читать информацию по ссылками, которые дают.

Comment: @Grundy я прочитал это и что? `Функция pow через return вызывает метода setTimeout с аргументом pow(рекурсия), который возвращает свой id = 1 и по идеи вызов функции должен почиститься. Возможно есть правило, которое предотвращает зачишения функции, и в следствии в консоли будут отображаться стеки, но я ни где не нашел информации по этому поводу.`

Comment: _я прочитал это и что?_ - то, что ты это значение умножаешь потом на переданный `x`.

Comment: У тебя полностью неверные рассуждения, потому что ты думаешь, что ты можешь попасть **внутрь** `setTimeout`

Comment: Собственно в случае с setTimeout даже рекурсии нет, потому что setTimeout **не вызывает** функцию, которую ей передают

Comment: @Grundy по поводу попасть внутрь (там есть пример) `...И в дополнение хочу еще добавить, что вроде как setTimeout просто создает "массив" в которой просто храниться очередь, и потом из нее(из очереди) идет уже вызов той функции, которую я туда передал.` По воду `pow(2, 3);  return x * setTimeout(pow, 1000, x, n - 1);`: return 2 * 1 = 2 и функция должна очиститься, но на скрине стеки есть, а значит контекст вызова не очистился и ждет возврата значения, ну или я хз как это работает ибо я для этого создал вопрос, и написал свои мысли по этому поводу, что бы было легче объяснять где я не прав.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68638/discussion-between-grundy-and--).